# Как вывести контент на главной странице Magento?

Tags: cms, magento

делаю мобильную версию магазина, который сделан на magento. проблема в том, что на десктопе отображается содержимое поля контент, а на мобильной - нет. пробовал менять шаблоны, но результат тот же. выходит, что где то не прописано в xml слоях, что именно на ГЛАВНОЙ надо выводить содержимое контента. буду признателен за любые мысли по этому поводу

Answer (score 1):

Написать в layout что твоя страница будет грузиться раньше чем маджентовская.
Просто главное не перепутать папку с темами

Comment: это все верно, да только почему то контент не выводится только на главной странице. как пример бралась мобильная тема iphone и вот в ней почему то нету на главной контента.

Comment: Кинь лейаут свой , где ты указываешь загрузку